# How to prevent a link inside a label from triggering a checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this label:

```
<label><input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="terms">terms</a> and would like to continue</label>
```

However, the link inside the label opens a foundation 5 reveal modal. This works fine, but clicking on the link also checks the checkbox.

How can I prevent the checkbox from being checked when the link is clicked?

Comment: This might be browser related In this fiddle (using chrome) I can't reproduce the described behaviour : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/ym6K7/

Comment: @kevinius — I can't reproduce your problem. Clicking the link does not check the checkbox. Either the problem is browser specific or depends on some JavaScript you have already. I think you need to add more detail to your question (including enough code to reproduce it)

Comment: I just tested in Chrome as well, and could not reproduce

Comment: In the fiddle above, when you click "and hold" on the link, you will see that this triggers the checkbox.

Comment: It is changing the checkbox value on label text click. http://jsfiddle.net/9UNwG/

Comment: @kevinius — when I do that, the checkbox changes colour while I hold the button down, but it never gets checked.

Comment: By default, a link inside a label will not trigger the checkbox. There must be some javascript interfering

Comment: In the fiddle, if you click and hold you see the checkbox getting triggered. Of course, if you release the click, the page will follow the link and reload. But you clearly see that the checkbox is getting triggered.

Comment: There's a really easy solution to this, don't put an anchor in a label -> **http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/9UNwG/2/** (even if it's not really valid)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should just need to bind an event to the link that calls `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()`

JQuery for all links in labels:

```
$(document).on("tap click", 'label a', function( event, data ){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'));
    return false;
});
```

Pure javascript (you need to set an id on the link you want to follow)

```
var termLink = document.getElementById('termLink');
var termClickHandler = function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();    
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open(termLink.href, termLink.target);
    return false;
};
termLink.addEventListener('click', termClickHandler);
termLink.addEventListener('touchstart', termClickHandler);
```

These expect the link target to be set to `_self` or `_blank` to open in the same window or a new window respectively.

Answer (score 13):

Since multiple labels can point to the same checkbox, you can modify the text to consist of two labels (pointing to the checkbox) and the anchor text in the middle.

```html
<input id="cb" type="checkbox">
<label for="cb">I agree to the</label>
<a href="#">terms</a>
<label for="cb">and would like to continue</label>
```

Using the above technique, clicking on the link doesn't effect the state of the checkbox, yet all the remaining text does.

Answer (score 6):

Another inline way:

```
<label>
     <input type="checkbox"> 
     I agree to the 
     <span  onclick="event.stopPropagation();">
          <a href="terms">terms</a>
     </span>
     and would like to continue
</label>
```

Comment: The most elegant solution

Answer (score 5):

Interactive elements inside interactive elements cause functional problems like this: it is undefined what happens when you click an `a` element inside a `label` element or vice versa. To avoid this, take the `a` element out of the `label` element, e.g.

```
<label><input type="checkbox">I agree</label> to the <a href="terms">terms</a>
and would like to continue
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" id="agree"><label for="agree">I agree</label> to the
<a href="terms">terms</a> and would like to continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop propagation of the click event on the link. This prevents the click event from bubbling up to the label.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation

Answer (score 0):

Try this . It works for me

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> I aggree to the <a href="terms" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block; z-index: 99999999999999999999; position: relative;">terms</a> and would like to continue</label>
```

Comment: Your z-index though. That's excessive. Better CSS practice is to use a z-index as low as possible that will work. Ideally if there is no z-index on the label text, z-index of 1 should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, please...

```
 <label>
      <input type="checkbox" /> I agree to the <a href="terms">terms</a> and would like to continue
 </label>
```

Comment: Tags do not have to be self closing in non-XHTML doctypes, the original poster's HTML is valid.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery:

```
$('label a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        span = $('<span onclick="event.stopPropagation();"></span>');
    span.html($this.clone());
    $this.replaceWith(span);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)