# CSS3 Menu Checkbox Hack, Hide Menu After Any Click On Itself

Tags: html, css

### Background

I am designing a menu for mobile devices, and trying to avoid JS entirely. I'm using the checkbox hack to show and hide the menu, and that is working.

### Problem

I want the menu to hide when a link is clicked. Right now this doesn't work.

### Current Code

```css
.toggle + a, .menu {
    display:none;
    z-index:10;
}
.toggle {
    display:block;
    padding:0 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    padding:none;
}
.toggle img {
    width:5%;
    float:right;
    padding:0;
}
[id ^= drop]:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
ul {
    width:100%;
}
ul li {
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:50%;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(63, 63, 63, 1);
    background:gray;
}
li:hover a {
    border-bottom:none;
    transform:none;
}
ul li a {
    width:90%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <label for="drop" class="toggle"><img src="images/menu_icon.png" alt="logo" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />

    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#design">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#location">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="#terms">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what is your html code?

Comment: Hi I have added my HTML code

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle, it will help to see what's wrong

Comment: Your CSS is badly formed with many typos.

Comment: @Paulie_D what typos? Everything is spelt correctly. The layout on Stack Overflow is what SO code block button has done to it, I don't write my CSS like that but that is what happens when it has been edited

Comment: @Finrod please see: https://jsfiddle.net/wonrL458/ If you click the check box the menu drops down, but click a link and the menu stays it doesn't disappear

Comment: I've fixed the typos in your question to get rid of what seemed to be the problem. Mind if I edit the question to make it more clear?

Comment: No problem, I have made the main issue bold. I will have to use jQuery for the menu if it cannot be done in CSS, trying to avoid it as the site has resource intensive images already (beyond my control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick Answer

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. You'll need some JS to create the exact effect you want.

---

#### Close Approximation With No JS

If you move the entire menu and input inside the `label` element, than any click on that menu should close the menu. I've done this in the snippet below.

The problem is that a click on an actual `a` element doesn't seem to trigger the label. It's strange because according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755802/a-link-inside-a-label-also-triggers-the-checkbox-how-to-prevent), it should, and people are concerned with preventing it. It might be browser specific.

```css
.toggle + a, .menu {
    display:none;
    z-index:10;
}
.toggle {
    display:block;
    padding:0 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    padding:none;
}
.toggle img {
    width:5%;
    float:right;
    padding:0;
}
[id ^= drop]:checked + ul {
    display: block;
}
ul {
    width:100%;
}
ul li {
    display:block;
    width:50%;
    margin-left:50%;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(63, 63, 63, 1);
    background:gray;
}
li:hover a {
    border-bottom:none;
    transform:none;
}
ul li a {
    width:90%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <label for="drop" class="toggle">
            <img src="http://retailadvocates15.nrf.com/sites/all/themes/nrf_events/images/mobile_menu_icon.gif" alt="logo" />
            <input type="checkbox" name="drop" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#home" class="smoothScroll">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#design" class="smoothScroll">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#location" class="smoothScroll">Location</a></li>
                <li><a href="#terms" class="smoothScroll">Terms</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery" class="smoothScroll">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </label>
```

Comment: Hi @Andy please note that my CSS file doesn't have any spaces at all, the spaces you see above are what SO has done to my code as I have had it validated with the w3c validator

Comment: If you see my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wonrL458/ - This is how my CSS looks no spaces and the menu still doesn't hide

Comment: I see your snippet works for the drop down as mine does on my site, the issue I have is the menu isn't auto hiding when you click on one of the links which is what I am requesting the help with. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer to as close as can be done with just CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have to implement jQuery on this as CSS isn't going to be the best option, unless I could just leave it

Comment: Since this answered your question (though we wish the answer was different), could you go ahead and mark it as the answer so that other people who happen to look at it in the future can quickly find it?