# Allow Clicking of Link in Bootstrap Checkbox Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a combination of Bootstrap and FontAwesome to create some touch accessible checkbox controls. As part of the text label for the checkbox, I would like to include a link to another page, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm guessing there is a stopPropagation() call being made in the Bootstrap JavaScript that is causing the issue, but I can't find a way around that. My HTML code is below.

```
<div class="btn-touch btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn" for="cbAgree">
        <input id="cbAgree" type="checkbox" name="cbAgree" />
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i>
        <span>I agree to the <a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>Terms & Conditions</a></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle that better illustrates the iss:
https://jsfiddle.net/bepsh3wt/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755802/a-link-inside-a-label-also-triggers-the-checkbox-how-to-prevent

Comment: thanks, that did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the link cbrawl provided had the solution. the below jquery solved my problem, thanks!

```
$('.btn-touch').on('click', 'label a', function (e) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('target'));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bepsh3wt/4/

It needs `<form>` tags and optionally you can hide the input:checkbox

```
<div class="btn-touch btn-group btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons">
<form>
    <label class="btn" for="MainContent_MainContent_lvTrip_cbYCJAgree_0">
        <input id="MainContent_MainContent_lvTrip_cbYCJAgree_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$MainContent$MainContent$lvTrip$ctrl0$cbYCJAgree" />
        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-2x"></i>
        <span>I agree to the <a href='/Terms' target='_blank'>Terms & Conditions</a></span>
    </label>
</form>
</div>
```